# How to call callback inside other function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, waterfall

I am trying to build a simple node waterfall via async module.
I'm just getting started with asynchronous programming in node.

Basically - how to call `callback()` inside `http.request` function to continue waterfall AFTER `response` IS END?

```
async.waterfall([
            function (callback) {
                var req = http.request(options, function (response) {
                    var str = ''
                    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                        str += chunk;
                    });

                    response.on('end', function () {
                        /* I want to call callback() AFTER `response` is END */
                    });
                });
                req.end();
            },
            function (response, callback) {

                // some operations WITH request `output`

            }], function (err, results) {
                // end
        });
```

Comment: Just calling callback() in the `response.on('end', function () {});` should work fine in your case. See [documentation on http stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end)

Comment: oh :) Thanks for help! Really So easy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript nested function see all parent variables. It is called closure.

That's why you can call your callback directly in the end event listener:

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        var req = http.request(options, function (response) {
            var str = ''
            response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                str += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function () {
                /* I want to call callback() AFTER `response` is END */

                callback(null, str);
            });
        });
        req.end();
    },
    function (response, callback) {

    // some operations WITH request `output`

    }
], function (err, results) {
                // end
});
```

Comment: thanks for help. my fault that I tried to expand nested functions like this: response.on('end', function (callback){} and so on :)